# Well-founded relation, well-order.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, well-orders

> On the set $\mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$ we define the relation of *strict divisibility* with $$ a \text{ strictly divides } b \Leftrightarrow a | b \text{ and } a \neq b.$$
>   Do we get a well-founded relation? Do we get a well-order?

I'm stuck with proving that there doens't exist an infinite descending chain or a cycle. Is there any other type of way to prove that?

Thanks for the help.

> There was a slightly different question asked in [Well-founded ordering on natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2138944/well-founded-ordering-on-natural-numbers), but it didn't really help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a\text{ strictly divides }b\implies a<b$ (for $a, b\neq 0$). Use this and the well-ordering of the natural numbers under the standard ordering to show that you cannot have an infinite descending chain or a cycle.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Arthur, $1\mid0$ and $1\neq0$ so $1$ strictly divides $0$.

Comment: @drhab You're right. I done goofed.

Answer (score 1):

For being well founded only one thing is needed for a relation $R$: if $A$ is an arbitrary non-empty subset of $\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$ then can we always find an element $n\in A$ such that $n$ has no $R$-predecessors?

Here $m$ is a predecessor of $n$ if $mRn$.

Things are clear if $0\notin A$ (you can just take the smallest element of $A$).

If $A=\{0\}$ then you can take $n=0$.

If $0\in A$ and $A$ contains more elements then you can take the smallest element of $A-\{0\}$.

We are not dealing with a total order (hence not with a well-order) because e.g. the elements $4$ and $5$ are not comparable.